# iOS: Subclassing UIWebView URLRequest crash

Tags: ios, swift3, uiwebview, xcode8

I'm subclassing UIWebView but when I trying to make a request it crash with this error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Here is my implementation:

ViewController:

```
var web:MyWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
self.webPage = MyWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: self.webPage!)
}

class MyWebView: UIWebView,UIWebViewDelegate {


let urlStr = "http://apple.com"

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    scalesPageToFit = true
    scrollView.bounces = false
    delegate = self
    let urlRequest = URL(string: urlStr)
    let request = URLRequest(url: urlRequest!)
    self.loadRequest(request)

}
```

If check the value of urlRequest in the console:

```
po urlRequest
nil
```

Any of you knows what I'm doing wrong or why this urlRequest is set as nil?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: How do you initialize `MyWebView`, is it just an IBOutlet ?  if not paste code where you init it. where are your print statements?  How you get to print nil ?

Comment: Does it say on which line you get the fatal error?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me fine

```
import UIKit

    class MyWebView: UIWebView,UIWebViewDelegate  {


        let urlStr = "https://www.apple.com"

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        }

        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)
            scalesPageToFit = true
            scrollView.bounces = false
            delegate = self
            let urlRequest = URL(string: urlStr)
            let request = URLRequest(url: urlRequest!)
            self.loadRequest(request)
        }

    }
```

Then call it from a viewcontroller

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        let webView = MyWebView.init(frame: self.view.frame)
        self.view.addSubview(webView)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

[image]